# What is frequency-domain entropy in FFT result and how to calculate it?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, software-defined-radio

I am a programmer but quit bad on math..  I recently read an article which mentioned frequency-domain entropy,he calculated that thing from a FFT power spectrum but didn't tell me how to do that. I cannot find enough information online to understand what it is . I'm appreciate for any helps..

Here is part of article:
[image]

Comment: I've never heard of entropy being calculated in the frequency domain.  Entropy is used to calculate the average amount of bits required to convey information about a signal... this is a really watered down version of what it is, but that's what you can take away if you're in a hurry.  For signals... whether they are waveforms, images, etc., it boils down to computing a histogram. I don't see why you should go into the frequency domain to calculate the entropy of a signal.. or why you should even go into the frequency domain all together.  Can you link us to this article?  I'm rather skeptical.

Comment: Hi , this is due to machine learning usage , i need to fetch the features from some data as more as possible(but without thinking their actual physical meaning), the article is A comparison of Feature Extraction Methods for the Classification of Dynamic Activities From Accelerometer Data , written by IEEE member in 2009 march.

Comment: But if you know mathematically how to calculate it please tell me :)

Comment: @Yank could you please give me the source of this article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Frequency domain entropy, also known as a (Power) Spectral Entropy calculation is done in following steps:

1. Calculate the FFT of your signal.
2. Calculate the PSD of your signal by simply squaring the amplitude spectrum and scaling it by number of frequency bins.

[image]

3. Normalize the calculated PSD by dividing it by a total sum.

[image]

4. Calculate the Power Spectral Entropy using a standard formula for entropy calculation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering ! The equation you explained is pretty clear,however I cannot find where these equation come from ,could you provide a link or something ..?

Comment: I am in travel now. It was one of the publications on PSE topic.

Comment: really thanks ,start reading some of it ,once I found the article I will approve your answer:)

Comment: Good luck! Try to search for something like *extraction of spectral entropy feature for eeg signals*. That was definitely one of the BioMed & Info conferences.Obviously there is plethora of different papers with that. I used it only for capturing of the equations, since SO is picky about TeX.

Comment: Wonderful!!! Is there a restriction with the base of logarithm? I found the same with log2 [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10137/spectral-entropy-calculation-in-matlab)